# Found nil while setting value of a label inside Collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**Case:**

I'm using a collection view inside a UIView, I've connected it as an outlet called `'partsCollectionView'`. I've created a cell with identifier `'cell'` and a custom class `'SelectionCollectionViewCell'` for that cell. Inside the cell, I've got a label called 'cellTitle'.

**Error:** `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

I'm facing the error while setting the value of that label inside '`cellForItemAt`' Method.

**Here are the concerned views:**

Cell description,

[image: Cell Description Image]

and, collection View Description

[image: The collection View]

The Cell Class is:

```
import UIKit

class SelectionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!
}
```

The class where I'll use the collection view is:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

let array = ["small","Big","Medium","Very big","Toooo big String","small"]

class SelectionCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var partsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var instructionsView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.partsCollectionView.register(SelectionCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }


     func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = partsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectionCollectionViewCell

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.cellTitle.text = array[indexPath.row]

        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.07843137255, green: 0.6862745098, blue: 0.9529411765, alpha: 0.6819349315)
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let name = array[indexPath.row]

        let attributedName = NSAttributedString(string: name)

        let width = attributedName.widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: 20.0)

        return CGSize(width: width + 40, height: 30.0)
    }
}

extension NSAttributedString {

    func widthWithConstrainedHeight(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

        return boundingBox.width
    }
}
```

**Update:** This is how it looks if I skip setting the title text. The title will come inside those rounded boxes.

[image: How it looks without Setting title]

Comment: did you checked which value is nil?

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: @AshishKakkad it seems like it is saying there is no label called cellTitle inside this cell. I've tried renaming removing and creating new one, cleaning etc.

Comment: @rmaddy I've written that in Error part.. While setting the value of that label inside 'cellforrowat'

Comment: I'm not positive but I think your issue is related to your use of `self.partsCollectionView.register(...` in `viewDidLoad`. Try removing that line since your cell is setup in Interface Builder.

Comment: Not related but why do you optional downcast the item in an array which is clearly `[String]`?

Comment: @vadian just tried everything like hard code, if let, guard and everything else before asking a question.

Comment: @rmaddy if i remove that, the application will crash before loading this view only.

Comment: Just write `let name = array[indexPath.row]`. No `if let`.

Comment: @vadian thanks but that's not the error I'm concerned about right now.

Comment: I know. That's why I wrote *not related*.

Comment: Try to set exception breakpoints and check what is nil. It's small mistake I think.

Comment: @AshishKakkad bro the error is in this line ''cell.cellTitle.text = array[indexPath.row] " , and the value on right hand side is not empty, on the left hand the cell can't be empty cuz other things are working fine..

Comment: When you are assigning everything in storyboard then there is no need to register in viewDidLoad. Also check if you have assigned reuse identifier in IB.

Comment: @SanketBhavsar Please pay attention to the kind of error I've mentioned. It's not related to reuse Id. Also see the question till end, if I skip one line to assign the value, It works fine.

Comment: @AshishSharma show your SelectionCollectionViewCell class code completely

Comment: @RajeshKumarR that's the complete code.

Comment: Collectionviewcell contains only one label?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR yes mate, only one!

Comment: what is the value of reuseIdentifier string?  Did you try by deleting         `self.partsCollectionView.register(SelectionCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

Comment: @AshishSharma if possible can you please share your this much bundle of work. Because i tried this same as per your code and everything works well. May be there is some small mistake while you setting up collection view cell related set up in storyboard.

Comment: try to delete and drag a new title label from storyboard. i too had same issue once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just minor mistake is there I think, In `cellForItemAt indexPath` Please update following line,

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SelectionCollectionViewCell
```

I just paste your code and got following output, nothing else,

[image]

If you still unable to produce desired output, just delete existing `UILabel` from `SelectionCollectionViewCell` and add it again.

**FYI**. No need to register cell in `viewDidLoad()` method

Comment: Tried the same earlier too, didn't work!
 just worked in this attempt.

Comment: Thank you, let me know in case of any help :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line from `viewDidLoad`.

```
    self.partsCollectionView.register(SelectionCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

When you register a cell programmatically it creates a new collection view cell object. It doesn't get the cell from storyboard. So `cellTitle` will be nil

**OR**

Programmatically initialize the label in custom collection view cell

```
class SelectionCollectionViewCell:UICollectionViewCell {
    let  cellTitle = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(cellTitle)
        cellTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    }
}
```